# Android/Kotlin/GraphView - auto increment the value of x coordinate and also,not showing the labels on X Axis

Tags: android, kotlin, android-graphview

I am creating an app using Kotlin in which I have to plot a graph using certain value which are gathered at different points of time. Now, I want my code to automatically increase the value of x-coordinate of the graphview while I pass ony the value of the y coordinate. Also, i do not want to show the labels on the X-axis of the graphView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? It is not a code writing service.

Comment: First of all, thanks for being rude. And yeah, I have a question. I want to know how to increment the value of x coordinate while plotting a graph in Android using GraphView. I have values for y coordinates which I am stroring in an ArrayList but there is no value of x-axis. It just have to increment wirh each value of x coordinate. I can't post my code here due to some boundations.